# value of type '[CChar]' has no member 'extend'

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

I got this Error in iOS during swift migration

```
func () {
 var tmpChar : [CChar] = []
tmpChar.extend(Array(repeating: 0, count: 32 - tmpChar.count))//error at this line
}
```

So my question is what is meaning of this error and How to solve it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: since this code doesn't make any sense, might you post the original code?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. `Array` does not respond to `extend`. Please read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array) to find the appropriate API

Comment: `extend()` is from Swift 1.2.